# JavaScript code is not executed inside footer CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to CSS and JavaScript.

My requirement is I have a dynamic page where footer should stay always at bottom, Let me make more clear if I have less content then footer should be at bottom leaving space till end of page, at the same time if there is more content then also footer should be at bottom after showing the whole content.

I have searched and found various ways like CSS Sticky footer but unfortunately couldn't solve my issue.

What I have tried:

I have found 2 ways to keep footer always at bottom use `bottom:0` but this one is working only when content is less (fills half of the page) one more method is using `flex` this one works only when content exceeds the page like if content is less then footer is coming exactly after the last line (May be at middle of the page).

So I have tried to find the length of the each div of the page and then apply the condition to use either of one at run time. This is where I am getting stuck as when I write JavaScript code inside footer of CSS code is not getting executed.

Below is code:

```
footer{
    <Script>
     var x=document.getElementById("toppart").clientHeight;
     document.getElementById("toppart").innerHTML = x;
     var y=document.getElementById("bottompart").clientHeight;
     document.getElementById("bottompart").innerHTML = y; 

     if (+x + +y < screen.Height){
    then{

    clear: both;
<!--position: absolute;-->
<!-- bottom: 0; -->
left:0;
right:0;
padding: 1rem;
color: white;
background-color: black;
text-align: center;
width:100%;
min-height: 100%;
display: flex;
<!--min-height: 100vh; -->
flex-direction: column;
}
else{

       clear: both;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
padding: 1rem;
color: white;
background-color: black;
text-align: center;
width:100%;
}
</Script>
    }
```

Above is not executed if I write footer inside Script tag.. If I don't use script tag then I can use the code.

Full code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html min-height:100%;box-sizing: border-box;>
<head >

<style >
div.container {
    width: 100%;
    <!--border: 1px solid gray;-->
}

 div.toppart{
width: 100%;
height: 50%
border: 1px solid red;
}

div.bottompart{
width: 100%;
height: 50%
} 

/*div.middlepart{
width: 100%;
height: 50%
}  */

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


header {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    <!--clear: left;-->
    text-align: center;
}


footer{
    <Script>
if(5+5<5)
    then{

    clear: both;
<!--position: absolute;-->
<!-- bottom: 0; -->
left:0;
right:0;
padding: 1rem;
color: white;
background-color: black;
text-align: center;
width:100%;
min-height: 100%;
display: flex;
<!--min-height: 100vh; -->
flex-direction: column;
}
else{

       clear: both;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
padding: 1rem;
color: white;
background-color: black;
text-align: center;
width:100%;
}
</Script>
    }
```

Comment: Have you mixed JS and CSS in your first code example? That is impossible!

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn yes.. actually I have done that... looks like I have done a mistake.. thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't go in your CSS, it goes in its own `<script>` tag similar to how CSS goes in its own `<style>` tag.

Additionally your javascript doesn't look correct either. You can't mix javascript `if/else` logic with CSS like that. You can change stylings via javascript with `ele.setAttribute("style","clear:both;width:200px;")` though first you should read a javascript tutorial to help you understand its general concepts.

Comment: thanks for answer... will try and accept it as answered